# sanitize data for SQL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, escaping, sql-injection, sanitization

I have a bunch of forms that have various input elements. I want to sanitize these on the server side (*yes*, I'm using server-side JavaScript) to use these inputs as parameters, and prevent special characters to be malformed.

Before you go, like "this belongs not in the realm of JavaScript", etc., etc.

I am using a multi-million licensed software solution, that well has JavaScript but apparently has no standard functions like this out of the box. So, whatever I am using, I can assure you that you probably have never touched it or heard of it. And it supports server side javascript, because well, the language is cool.

My first objective is to sanitize data before it goes in the database, and I just love the way for example how Ruby labels foreign data: tainted. And I rather have no tainted data. So I could google and copy paste some poor regex from here and there, and I got some sad example. However, I would like to have a function that would be said "well, that takes off 70% of the possible stuff from that data and a pretty darn good sanitize".

Basically a string from these elements should be escaped and I assume best practices are already existing for this wish of mine.

```
function sanitize(myString) { ... ; return myString }
```

How can I escape symbols like '#!? and other special characters and how i can i get them back in reverse? I am aware of the JavaScript escape method, but I want to know if a function is already debugged and public available before I re-invent the wheel.

I considered:
- JavaScript Escape
- Base64 Encoding
- Regex

I just rather ask the people who have written such functions before.

Thanks,

Comment: You do not want to sanitize your input with javascript, it can be disabled at the client side very easilly.

Comment: @Stefan: Again: *"I want to sanitize these **on the server side** to..."* (My emphasis). JavaScript != client side

Comment: @Shyam You're relying on an honest user. This is a **Bad Thing**. @Stefan H is right. @T.J. the description is ambiguous then. It's about escaping *server side* and *the JavaScript escape method*.

Comment: how did you end up using javascript on the server? there must be a better way to accomplish this...

Comment: I don't quite follow...  How would you do server side javascript sanitization?

Comment: For user input of any sort, you'll be far safer with stored procedures than building some sort of string through concatenation.

Comment: @Stefan: *"I don't quite follow... How would you do server side javascript sanitization?"* By using JavaScript on the server. JavaScript has been used on the server side since 1996 or so (in Netscape's web/application server). Every version of IIS released in the last 12 years or so has had server-side "JScript". Recently, server-side JavaScript has had a resurgence, particularly in the form of v8cgi and NodeJS, but there are others as well.

Comment: @Shyam What database and database adapter are you using with your server-side JS?

Comment: Maybe he's using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), but I think it's more likely that he's just confused.

Comment: I had no idea that there was a server side javascirpt, and if that is indeed what teh OP is using, then I will prompty remove my answer, but like @treeFace said, i think they are likely just confused.

Comment: @tenfour: *"how did you end up using javascript on the server? there must be a better way to accomplish this."* Why? I use JavaScript on the server all the time. JS is a great language, why write half your app in one language and the other half in another??

Comment: @Stefan: Could well be. My question is: Where is the guy and why hasn't he clarified?

Comment: Actually, I use JavaScript API on top of Rhino inside an application server. The JavaScript I use is to manipulate the data that is already passed the part where the user has entered the data. JavaScript is a language, not a just browser feature.

Comment: @Shyam You sure showed us ;-). Incidentally, it might've helped to make this clear in your original question.

Comment: If I would be relying on a honest user, why the hell would I want to sanitize their input?

Comment: @Shyam I suppose we're all just a bunch of reflex-action know-it-alls when we see a question that involves "JavaScript", "SQL", and "sanitization". I'm sure Pavlovian studies could be done on SO regulars using a post like this X-D

Comment: @Shyam: I've added a parenthetical to the question so people know you're not just confused, but genuinely using server-side JavaScript.

Comment: :) No harm done. I expected most of the reactions to be like this ;)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: why would anyone using server side javascript be confused :)

Comment: This is a valid question because of Node.js.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**See update below**

You're reinventing the wheel. Whatever you're using to talk to your database should have some kind of "prepared statement" concept. In Java it's literally the `PreparedStatement` class, but essentially any database access system should have something similar. You use these so that you're not building up SQL statements as strings. So for instance, conceptually:

```
preparedStatement = prepare("insert into mytable (id, name) values (?, ?)")
preparedStatement.setField(0, theId);
preparedStatement.setField(1, theName);
```

*Not*:

```
statement = "insert into mytable (id, name) values ('" + theId + "', '" + theName + "')"
```

...which is asking for injection attacks.

The "prepared statement" concept centralizes escaping to the database link layer, which is well-prepared to handle it. <s>If you tell people what you're using to access your database, they'll be able to point you at the relevant mechanism.</s> See below.

Just for the avoidance of doubt: You're doing this escaping **on the server**, right? I mean, that's how I read it, you've actually said *"I want to sanitize these on the server side..."*. But just in case you were thinking of doing it client-side: **You can't**. Nothing, absolutely nothing, that the client-side sends you can be trusted, as it can be faked. You must do this server-side.

---

**Update**: You've commented that you're using Rhino in an application server. Excellent! Then just [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and let your JDBC driver handle it for you. *(For non-Java lurkers: Rhino is JavaScript for the Java VM. It's brilliant.)*

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't have access to a query binding/prepared statement class, you can simply escape the values as you concatenate them into the string. In PHP, you can ensure that a value is an integer by using `intval()` and you can escape strings by using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Well, the database is just a record facility for my purposes. I like the data I inside my application to be untainted, so the function I kind of looking for is like application wide. That's why I want a JavaScript function so I can reuse it everywhere. Storing to the database specifically would be a very first important use case of that function.

Comment: @Shyam: Ah, fair 'nuff. <s>I seem to have added a database to your question that wasn't there.</s> Wait, no I didn't, you've got `sql` and `sql-injection` tags on this.

Comment: well, with non-sanitized data that might be used in "sql" statements a "sql injection" would be the first scenario for the malicious hacker that sees like the input element. The wonders one can do with '

Comment: Arrrr.. but that would be like giving all the fun to the database. Basically car-washing a javascript string before giving it to the database, that would be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @Shyam: Yeah, I understand. I'm not aware of any pre-built solution, I'm afraid. Certainly not `escape`, that's not what it's for.

Comment: Well, I tried some regex, so I know how to get rid of the ', but there are many ways. I thought about base64 encoding for example, but I wonder if that is really for escaping and sanitizing.

Comment: There isn't really a standard function for this, the prepared statements through JDBC seems like the closest best thing. Thanks for the correction and well-formed answer.