# How can I use JS to build a prepared statement for a sqlite UPDATE from an array of key values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prepared-statement

I want to build a function that builds a prepared statement for a SQlite UPDATE
query. My current approach is to simply build a string and send this sql to the
database. But you can only do that if you don't care about security at all ;-)

**My current function:**

```js
const newBrandData = {name: "def"};
const brand = {id: 1, name: "abc", prop1: ""};

update(brand, newBrandData) {
    const keyValues = [];
    Object.keys(newBrandData).forEach(e => {
        keyValues.push(`${e} = "${newBrandData[e]}"`)
    });
        
    const sql = `UPDATE ${this.table} SET ${keyValues.toString()} WHERE id = ?`;
    const params = [brand.id];

    return this.run(sql, params);
}
```

Comment: This one will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494662/sanitize-data-for-sql-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you @BehrouzPooladrak but this does not help me at the moment ;-) I am interested in the algorithm for dynamically generating a key value set for the update function. But thanks anyway for the interesting link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question, but you can avoid concatenating key values by using placeholders everywhere:

```js
const keyValues = [];
const params = [];
Object.keys(newBrandData).forEach(e => {
  keyValues.push(`${e} = ?`);
  params.push(newBrandData[e]);
});
const sql = `UPDATE ${this.table} SET ${keyValues.toString()} WHERE id = ?`;
params.push(brand.id);
```

Comment: Thank You Heiko! That is exactly what i want! You understood me right :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely on the right track. You only have to change two things:

1. replace `keyValues.push(`${e} = "${newBrandData[e]}"`)` **with** `keyValues.push(`${e} = ?`)` `.
2. replace `const params = [brand.id];` **with** `const params = [...Object.values(newBrandData), brand.id];`

```js
update(brand, newBrandData) {
    const keyValues = [];
    Object.keys(newBrandData).forEach(e => {
        keyValues.push(`${e} = ?`)
    });
        
    const sql = `UPDATE ${this.table} SET ${keyValues.toString()} WHERE id = ?`;
    
    const params = [...Object.values(newBrandData), brand.id];
    return this.run(sql, params)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max! Your answer is correct! But Heiko was first ;-) i will use your sugested destcructor!